# accessing subsampled dataframe by mask on fully sampled dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is working code

```
import pandas as pd

full_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, ]
})
sub_df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "b": [5, 6, 7, 8]
})

factor = 4

print(full_df)
print("_____")
print(sub_df)

mask = full_df["a"] == 2
print(full_df[mask])
```

prints

> ```
>     a
> 0   1
> 1   1
> 2   1
> 3   1
> 4   2
> 5   2
> 6   2
> 7   2
> 8   3
> 9   3
> 10  3
> 11  3
> 12  4
> 13  4
> 14  4
> 15  4
> _____
>    a b
> 0  1 5
> 1  2 6
> 2  3 7
> 3  4 8
>    a
> 4  2
> 5  2
> 6  2
> 7  2
> ```

I now want to access `sub_df` at indices that correspond to `full_df`'s indices, only where `full_df` was masked.

something like (the not working) `print(sub_df[mask % factor])`

expected:

> ```
>    a b
> 1  2 6
> ```

How to do this in pandas?

Comment: I can't understand the logic, what's the significant of `factor` here?

Comment: @QuangHoang factor is the factor in which `full_df` was subsampled to obtain `sub_df`. If it were `2`, then `sub_df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4]})` and result would be `[2, 2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
factor=4

new_mask = mask[np.arange(len(full_df))%factor==0]
sub_df[new_mask.values]
```

Output:

```
    a
1   2
```

Comment: I want to apply the mask to the `sub_df`. in reality, it has different data, I just used the same data to be clearer (which didn't work)

Comment: I edited and added a `b` column which is not in `full_df`, maybe it will be clearer